# How can I trigger a Featherlight gallery from an svg path with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, featherlight.js

I'm trying to open a featherlight gallery from an svg path on click event but without luck. I'm able to get a normal gallery (as in Featherlight Gallery examples) working fine but triggering gallery from non-gallery element just won't work.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#svg-path').on('click', function(){
    $('.gallery-items').featherlightGallery({
      openSpeed: 300
    });
  })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5z4n4kxa/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `$.featherlightGallery(...)` to open a gallery; `$(...).featherlightGallery)` is used to bind.